# Given 2 strings find the indexes where one string occurs in another

Tags: python, string, find

As the title says, I have 2 strings, something like:

```
string = """
for i in x:
    for y in z[i]:
        print y
"""
s2 = "for"
```

What I want to get is:

```
[1, 17] # positions where "for" starts in string..
```

Is there any built-in function for this, or a better way than multiple `find`s??

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I just gave a close vote to my own question..

Comment: I'm just happy that my answer echoes the accepted answer there! :-) I wasn't aware of the existence of the other question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's fine, I've done that once too... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use multiple finds, or use a regular expression and [`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
[match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(s2), string)]
```

`re.finditer()` yields [match objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject), and we use the [`re.MatchObject.start()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) here to just pick out the start index of matches found.

I used [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to prevent regular expression meta characters in `s2` to be interpreted to make sure the behaviour is the same as multiple `str.find()` calls.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = """
... for i in x:
...     for y in z[i]:
...         print y
... """
>>> s2 = "for"
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(s2), string)]
[1, 17]
```

Comment: This is better than multiple finds..